# Changing the code in assembly

Tags: c#, reflector

I have a dll file is written on C #, I opened the file via the Reflector, the file is the code

```
if (a! = 5)
{
}
```

How can I change the code on

```
if (a == 5)
{
}
```

I still have the plugin Reflexil

Comment: @Brian - If Jon Skeet is awake now, this question will surely get a proper answer in a few minutes ;)

Comment: To add to what Brian said, if you don't do the minimum participation in the community here people will be less likely to help you. Please vote for answers that are helpful, and accept answers (click the big tick on the left of the answer, under the votes) which best answer your question.  Without doing this you run the risk of having people start to ignore your questions.

Comment: heh, you can do this with a hex editor, just gotta flip the right 75 into a 74 ;) if you have a disassembler at hand, you can spot the relevant instructions and flip the 75 to 74. something you normally don't do while reversing :) the opcode you're looking for is JNE (0x75) and you want it to be JE (0x74)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [MSIL Disassembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Decompile using that tool, apply changes in IL and compile back again using [MSIL Assembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

This will work smoothly if compiled app is not protected.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the answer about modifying the IL is correct, you can also use [Denis Bauers plugin for reflector](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) to disassemble the code and create a new project from it.  You can then recompile that project to produce a new dll.

This allows you to make the change in a more familiar environment, rather than having to deal with the IL.  you can also choose the language you want to make the changes in.

If the assembly needs to be signed then you might have problems getting it to load again.

Comment: Reflexil comes with a complete VB/C# editor and intellisense allowing code injection directly from Reflector. see: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/msil/reflexil.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Other Alternatives are [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) or the Resharper 6.0 which also contains a disassembler.